# configure phabricator's admin account not via UI

Tags: phabricator

I am trying to configure phabricator's admin account which appears when entering to it's home page on the first time.
According to [here](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_accounts_and_registration/) I can use `phabricator/ $ ./bin/accountadmin`, but it's not setting admin's password - unless I recover the account, get an (partially) arbitrary link and set everything inside manually. 
but - I want to **fully** configure it without UI, but with phabricator's CLI/linux commands.
How can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phabricator can not be fully installed with the help of cli, The problem is the Authentication method that should be set for the application is not configurable with cli at the moment. Take look at [this issue](https://secure.phabricator.com/T4200) for more information.